# xdotool returning different output when executed from crontab

Tags: shell, cron, xdotool

So I was making a script that monitors my app usage. It does so by running a cronjob every minute, and cronjob in question checks which window is focused on and increments its counter by 1.

Other parts of code are insignificant, this is important part:

```
focused=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
pid=$(xdotool getwindowpid $focused 2>/dev/null)
[ "$pid" ] &&
    pname="$(cat /proc/$pid/comm)" ||
    pname="idling"
```

I tested the script, and running it from `dmenu`, terminal or `i3blocks`, `pname` is what it is supposed to be every time. But when I run it from crontab, `echo $pname` ends up resulting in `idling` every single time.

I checked if I'm running my crontab as my user and not as root.

edit: Ideally I want to keep all my cronjobs in personal crontab, not in `/etc/crontab` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you do not mention DISPLAY environment variable at all. With xdotool, you'd be using X11, so the variable DISPLAY should match the DISPLAY variable from when you run this in a terminal in your graphical session:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

edit: adding Quasimodo's comment here in the answer:

Try `export DISPLAY=:0` in your script.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` from terminal returns ":0" and when I add DISPLAY=":0" in the script that runs as cronjob nothing changes.

Comment: @Quasímodo oh it works, thank you